# Local property editors types in DBReg

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, propertyeditor

I'm creating my own DB-aware grid control for Delphi 7. In `DBReg` unit Delphi registers the property editors for db-aware controls but almost all of them are local types, so I cannot re-use them:

```
TDataSetProperty
TNestedDataSetProperty
TDataSourceProperty
TLookupSourceProperty
TLookupDestProperty
TLookupIndexProperty
TLookupFieldProperty
```

Why they are local types and does it change in newer versions of delphi? And is it a good practice if I just copy it to my unit?

Comment: You're looking in the wrong place. :-) See the D7 help file (`Start->Borland Delphi 7->Help->Writing custom components`), which will take you to the `Component Writers Guide`. Expand the topic, and select `Making a control data aware`, looking particularly at `TDataLink`. Then look at `DBGrids.pas` instead of `DBReg.pas` for the way they used it in the `TDBGrid` and `TColumn` classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect that the designers confined these classes to implementation sections to ensure that other developers were not able to use them.

> Does it change in newer versions of delphi?

In XE3, and presumably in all other versions since Delphi 7, these types are still confined to the implementation section of `DBReg`.

> Is it a good practice if I just copy it to my unit?

No it would not–that would be a clear violation of the Delphi license.

Comment: It's a good occasion to practice writing my own property editors, though :)

Comment: But perhaps he can just obtain them via OTA and co-register them to his classes as well ?

Comment: @Arioch'The Could you expand a little?

Comment: i don't have D7 so i don't know if those registered property editors are exposed there or not. If sources and documents would not be enough You may make your editor and try to put breakpoint on its creation - perhaps you'd get the code that gets editor class for given object. I remember in D5 i found the array of registered property editors - just to find out that it has no public getter. I remember in some later Delphi it extended. But i don't remember if it applies to D7 or not.

Comment: in XE2 they are not local... // one interest name i see - without docs... http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/DesignIntf.RegisterPropertyMapper

Comment: These classes are all confined to implementation section of DBReg in XE2.

Comment: in XE2 PropertyCategoryList of "C:\RAD Studio\9.0\source\ToolsAPI\PropertyCategories.pas" lets you effectively enumerate registered properties and their editors.

Comment: GetComponentProperties used by procedure TClassProperty.GetProperties in "C:\RAD Studio\9.0\source\ToolsAPI\DesignEditors.pas"